# Nash equilibrium and score

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I'm investigating a 3-player Nash game, and I need a sanity check.

Is it true that the outcome of a 3 player nash game need not be determined, even when the strategies are pure? The game is cubicup, where only one player can win, deterministic, finite actions/space. Specifically, it seems like one player is doomed but can 'choose who to lose to' with its nash-equilibrium strategies.

Comment: What's a "Nash game"? And what do you mean by "the outcome need not be determined"? That the Nash equilibrium is not unique?

Comment: just a game where nash equilibrium exists. Like chess or checkers; a normal board game really. A determined outcome is like 'player 1 wins', but i suspect that its something like 'player 1 wins or player 2 wins, depending on how player 3 would like to lose'

Comment: To determine an outcome, you need a solution concept for the game. Are you assuming that players play according to a Nash equilibrium? In that case the outcome would be determined if and only if there is a unique Nash equilibrium. You don't need $3$ players for there to be more than one Nash equilibrium; see e.g. the first example ("coordination game") in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium#Examples) on Nash equilibria.